# Isolating polarities on a series wired battery bank

Tags: batteries, isolation, polarity

Can anyone, with 100% certainty (that means you know what you are talking about) tell me how to "isolate" the positive from the negative posts electrically in one direction so I have a true 'positive' and a true 'negative' in a series wired battery bank with 3 12 volt marine top post batteries. I already know about Schottky barrier diodes but I am looking for a better product that does not have as much reverse leakage. I also am learning about N MOSFETS. Forward voltage will be 34- 36 volts and trying to convey a maximum of 180 Amps with a minimum of 140 Amps.
    Please help; thank you.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. I have no clue what you mean by "isolate" here. Physical distance usually isolates them enough for most purposes.

Comment: I think he's talking about a battery isolator.. used to isolate starting from deep cycle batteries (for example). It allows them both to charge from one source (alternator) but discharge independently to their respective loads. With three 12V batteries in series, I'd think regular (non-Schottky) fat rectifiers (eg. S300Y) would be pretty good. Only 370mV/battery drop.

Comment: I'm still working on "true positive" and "true negative". What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm guessing he's referring to unidirectional current flow, but hey, that's a WAG. He should post some schematics or other information.

Comment: Please say why do you want to isolate those batteries, why do you care about reverse leakage, etc. Show some circuits and describe, so far, what's wrong with them.

Comment: Spehro, please tell me what a "WAG" is? I could not get my diagram / schematic to upload. I am not referring to or looking for a battery isolator. Not physically isolate but rather to electrically isolate the connection from positive to negative(one battery to the next, hooked in series)so that the DC electricity will flow from the positive (+) to the negative (-) battery post but both will keep their respective polarities and of course not 'back' flow from negative (-) to positive in that same connector / jumper cable. Thank you all.

Comment: Also Spehro; why use a non Schottky diode / rectifier in stead of a Schottky with its inherent lower leakage rate and better reverse voltage blocking characteristics? Do you have a vendor and part # for that "fat rectifier" please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect three 12-volt batteries in series to create a nominal 36 volt battery bank, you simply connect the positive terminal of the bottom (most negative) battery to the negative terminal of the middle battery, and the positive of the middle battery to the negative of the top battery.  The negative terminal of the bottom battery will be the negative terminal of the full bank, and the positive terminal of the top battery will be the positive terminal of the bank.  There is no need for any additional components between or around the batteries.

Comment: Yes Peter I do know how to do that; hook up 3 batteries in series, thank you..... but that is not was I asked.

Comment: I don't think anyone who has commented on your question understands what you mean by "true positive" and "true negative" or why you want to isolate the negative terminal of one battery from the positive terminal of the next.  You will have to explain more clearly exactly what you want, or waht problem you are trying to solve, before we can truly answer your question (if indeed it can be answered).  You can add a schematic to your question by selecting "edit", then pressing "control-M".

Comment: Why I want to do this is really nobody's business, I was just looking for an answer to this "problem". I asked for competent answers and all I get is people who want to get a point for responding, even with a nosy question like "why do I want to do this"? (Kuba) It will be answered by someone who knows what they truly are talking about. Now please, if you do not know the true answer then do not respond with 'riff raff'. I have an idea on how to do it, I was just looking for confirmation, that is all. Thank you.